# What is the difference between statement level and object level parallel hint for a select Statement

Tags: oracle, parallelism

Does object level parallel hint affect the table settings for parallelism?
Will statement level parallel hint apply to only that particular query and won't affect any default settings?

Comment: Can you give examples of what you mean? Query hints will never change table settings.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you brief about difference between object level and statement level parallel hint? Eg in object level we mention table name also /*+ PARALLEL(temp_table,2) */ vs statement level /*+ PARALLEL(2) */

Comment: Thanks for the comment clarifying your question.  Can you [edit] your question to include that information.  Also, the answer would depend on whether there are multiple tables in the query.  Of course, if there is just one table in the query, the object level would be redundant.  Keep in mind parallelism can be specified in the table definition also.... So clarify your question with full example queries, per [mre].